# Create a Link from a List to a Document in Library that I can edit

Tags: list, document, hyperlink, datasheet, edit

I have two pages. One page contains all of the documents for this site. 
The second page contains four different Datasheet Lists. I am trying to add a column that will link to the documents in the library.

I used the hyperlink column but when I clicked on it to edit it did not save over the original document in the doc library. It just created a version and saved to my desktop.

I will have twenty resources assigned to many tasks so it would be nice to have the link to the document in the list.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. 
Thanks!
Megan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to use a lookup column. In the `Get information from` field, select the document library. In the `In this column` field, choose Title. When you create a new item, it lets you select any document in that library from a drop down, then creates a link to it.

That should satisfy your requirements to 1) edit what document it's linking to, and 2) open documents from the lists.